# Why pointer dereference is different object in slices

Tags: go

```
func Test(t *testing.T) {
    a1 := 5
    a2 := 6
    a3 := 7
    p1 := &a1
    p2 := &a2
    p3 := &a3
    s := make([]int, 0)
    s = append(s, *p1, *p2, *p3)
    a1 = 8
    if s[0] != 8 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Why does the test fail?
I don't have much experience in Go, but I thought that two variables can have the same value that is stored in one memory address. But what I see from the test bellow it's not correct. 
Doesn't it mean that if I want to change some variable from different places in my program I have to store it in variable and then use only pointers everywhere in the code?

Comment: You don't store pointers in your slice, but copies of the dereferenced values, aka the values themselves, the numbers. Compare with https://play.golang.org/p/MqQ2UjF1Zn1

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the use of slice types per se, and everything to do with the fact that you're storing `int` values.

It is true that `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` have type `*int` (pointer to int).  They point to `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` respectively (and those three have type `int`, due to the [default type rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), which dictate that the untyped constants `5`, `6`, and `7` become `int` here).  But this means that `*p1`, `*p2`, and `*p3` have type `int`.  So:

> ```
> s = append(s, *p1, *p2, *p3)
> ```

does the same thing as:

```
s = append(s, 5, 6, 7)
```

would do (given that `*p1` is 5, and so on, which we can see by just looking at the code—none of the `a` variables have changed yet).

You then change variable `a1` to 8.  So `*p1` is also now 8, but you've built your slice out of the three values 5, 6, and 7, and those values are not changed here.  If you print `*p1`, you will see that it is now 8.  If you assign to `*p2`, then print `a2`, you will see that `a2` is updated by assigning to `*p2`.

As [zerkms noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165631/why-pointer-dereference-is-different-object-in-slices#comment104555944_59165631), if you had built your slice out of type `*int` and made `s[0]` point to `a1`, *then* changing `a1` would also change `*s[0]`.  Similarly, changing `*s[1]` would change `a2`.  You didn't do that, though, so they don't.  Again, though, it's not a matter of whether you use a slice here, but rather whether the variables in question are pointers, and if so, what they point-to<sup>1</sup> at the time you use their values.

---

<sup>1</sup>I hyphenated this to avoid the urge to write "to what they point". :-)